# Not able to user Custom screen in Navigation Tab

Tags: acumatica

I have designed 4 custom pages to accept user defined fields of sales order. I am trying to access the pages from GI. 2 Screens are allowing me to map Order Type & Order Number, but other two is not allowing me to do the same

[image]

[image]

All the 4 screens are having the same view as given below

```
public PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>, And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>> CurrentDoc1;
```

I am not able to figure out the reason why it is behaving different.
Looking forward for any suggestion to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon the investigation of the source code provided within support case with Acumatica, there had been determined the following issues with your custom screen called Digital (KC109000):

- in the UpdateDigital BLC there should be declared 2 separate data views: CurrentDoc1 is the primary view and CurrentDocument is required to bound addition container controls to the SOOrder DAC:

  ```
  public class UpdateDigital : PXGraph<UpdateDigital, SOOrder>
  {
      public PXSelect<SOOrder> CurrentDoc1;

      public PXSelect<SOOrder,
          Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>,
              And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>> CurrentDocument;


      ...
  }
  ```
- key fields (OrderType and OrderNbr) can not be disabled neither is Aspx nor inside BLC, otherwise they won't be listed inside the Navigation Parameters' Field drop-down:

  ```
  <px:PXSelector ID="edOrderType" runat="server" DataField="OrderType" Enabled="True" AllowNull="False" >
  </px:PXSelector>
  <px:PXSelector ID="edOrderNbr" runat="server" DataField="OrderNbr" Enabled="True" >
  </px:PXSelector>
  ```
- CurrentDocument should be the data member for PXTab to not contradict with the primary view:

  ```
  <px:PXTab ID="tab" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="500px" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="CurrentDocument">
  ```

Once the changes described above had been made in the KC109000.aspx file and the UpdateDigital BLC, the Navigation Parameters' Field drop-down started showing SOOrder key field available for selection:

[image]